# error al obtener datos desde GSheet en listViewAdapter en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, google-hoja-de-cálculo

He seguido al ipe de la letra varios tutoriales para conseguir agregar datos GoogleSheet y mostrarlos en un listview, pero estoy obteniendo un error como si estuviera recibiendo un objeto nulo.Pero no logro encontrar aun el error y no cuento con el tiempo necesario para analizarlo. Agradezco cualquier ayuda o indicio de solución para este.
Ingreso datos por medio de la siguiente actividad :

```
public class AddItem extends MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText editTextItemName,editTextBrand,editTextPrice;
Button buttonAddItem;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.add_item);

    editTextItemName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_item_name);
    editTextBrand = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_brand);
    editTextPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_price);

    buttonAddItem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
    buttonAddItem.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//This is the part where data is transafeered from Your Android phone to Sheet by using HTTP Rest API calls

private void   addItemToSheet() {

    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Adding Item","Please wait");
    final String name = editTextItemName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String brand = editTextBrand.getText().toString().trim();
    final String price = editTextPrice.getText().toString().trim();




    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx8fVzzs1U2E7vdORYYJfYLNZTPwAjRSiIBVfp30GewwNWfTps/exec",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(AddItem.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();
            //here we pass params
            parmas.put("action","addItem");
            parmas.put("itemName",name);
            parmas.put("brand",brand);
            parmas.put("price",price);
            return parmas;
        }
    };
    int socketTimeOut = 50000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v==buttonAddItem){
        addItemToSheet();
        //Define what to do when button is clicked
    }
}
}
```

Luego estoy intentando obtenerlos en el listview que he creado y su respectivo adapter para mostrar los datos:

```
public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ListAdapter listAdapter;
ProgressDialog loading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.lv_items);

    obtenerItems();
}

private void obtenerItems() {
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Cargando","Espera por favor...",false,true);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx8fVzzs1U2E7vdORYYJfYLNZTPwAjRSiIBVfp30GewwNWfTps/exec?action=getItems",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    parseItems(response);
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );

    int socketTimeOut = 50000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(stringRequest);

}
private void parseItems(String jsonResposnce) {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonResposnce);
        JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("items");


        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

            String itemName = jo.getString("itemName");
            String brand = jo.getString("brand");
            String price = jo.getString("price");


            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
            item.put("itemName", itemName);
            item.put("brand", brand);
            item.put("price",price);

            list.add(item);


        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.list_item_row,
            new String[]{"itemName","brand","price"},new int[]{R.id.tv_item_name,R.id.tv_brand,R.id.tv_price});


    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    loading.dismiss();
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
2019-07-02 08:03:31.117 19383-19391/? E/art: Failed sending reply to 

debugger: Broken pipe
2019-07-02 08:04:22.672 19383-19383/pv.portafolioverde.gsheetexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pv.portafolioverde.gsheetexample, PID: 19383
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at pv.portafolioverde.gsheetexample.ListItem.parseItems(ListItem.java:107)
        at pv.portafolioverde.gsheetexample.ListItem.access$000(ListItem.java:28)
        at pv.portafolioverde.gsheetexample.ListItem$1.onResponse(ListItem.java:50)
        at pv.portafolioverde.gsheetexample.ListItem$1.onResponse(ListItem.java:47)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
```

Comment: Perdón por la ignorancia olvide revisar el ContentView de mi ListItem.java
Debí colocar luego de super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal error ocurre al configurar el `Adapter` en tu `ListView` ya que el valor de `ListView`  es null:

```
  listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

El problema se debe a que no estas definiendo el layout donde se debe encontrar el `ListView`, esto debe realizarse mediante `setContentView( )` y no esta definido en tu clase.

Agrega `setContentView(R.layout.<nombre de layout>)` y define que layout va a cargar.

```
public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ListAdapter listAdapter;
ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //* Aquí define en que layout se encuentra lv_items.
        setContentView(R.layout.???);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.lv_items);

        obtenerItems();
    }

...
...
```

Comment: Sip muchas gracias!